# How to stop Developer Console window from being tiny?

Tags: developer-console

When I start the Developer Console, it immediately changes it's size down to a very tiny window. Even though I drag it open, it never remembers the new size and always goes back to being small.

Is there any way to reset this so it stops that?

[image]

Comment: problems that we dev has to deal with :)

Answer (score 1):

You can delete your workspace, which should fix the problem.

[Help topic](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000332898&type=1)

> Description Developer Console menu may become non-functional
> sometimes, because of the workspace being in bad state. To restore the
> functionality, follow the following steps.  Resolution   Fix 1:
>
> 1. Login and open Developer Console by Chrome
> 2. Open Developer tools and select Network
> 3. Reload on Developer Console
>
> Fix 2:
>
> 1. Login to Workbench and go to REST Explorer
> 2. Use the following query in Workbench to get the IDEWorkspace
>
> /services/data/v31.0/tooling/query/?q=SELECT id, name from
> IDEWorkspace
>
> ID of IDEWorkspace is "1dexxxxxxxxxxxxxx".
>
> 3. Do GET operation for the found id with following query "/services/data/v29.0/tooling/sobjects/IDEWorkspace/1de1a0000014sEWAAY"
> 4. You will see the content of IDEWorkspace
> 5. Do DELETE operation on found record.
> 6. Re-open Developer Console.
> 7. Developer Console will work fine. As we created a new workspace and the old workspace has been deleted.And the slowness will also be
>    removed.

Comment: Fix 1 didn't have any effect for me. My menu is operational. I just need to drag the lower corner of the window to widen it in, and since it's so small, I have to catch it in a tiny area. I can't get into Workbench on this org for Fix 2.

Comment: @mannaggia Have you tried using your keyboard? Alt+Space, X should allow you to maximize the window.

Comment: Thanks - probably makes it slightly easier... In the mean time, I grabbed the URL and created a bookmark on my bookmarks bar, and that takes me to the Dev Console in a full browser window instead of the pop up window from within SF. That does keep its size.